# Postgres Write/Read Lock

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have multi threaded JEE application which run SELECT FOR UPDATE LIMIT 1; query on a Table with WHERE clause and Update row in each transaction, which create row-level write lock and do not block readers to read.

Is there any way to configure postgres, to stop readers to read rows with write lock?

Answer (score 5):

On postgres 9.5+ there is the `SKIP LOCKED` option:

> If you need to SELECT from a table and protect those rows from being updated until your transaction has completed, you would specify FOR UPDATE, but if some rows are locked, you can specify SKIP LOCKED to tell it to simply ignore those rows and just perform the operation on whichever rows it can access.

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What's_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.5#SKIP_LOCKED

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option for you if you are runnint Postgres <=9.4 where `NOWAIT` exists, but `SKIP LOCKED`.  This demonstrates the used of `CONTINUE` and `EXIT` in a `LOOP` in order to identify the next available unlocked single row.

```
DO $$
DECLARE 
    r RECORD;
    ... -- your variables 
BEGIN
    FOR r IN 
        SELECT some_id
          FROM some_table
         WHERE ... -- your conditions
         ORDER BY ... -- your ordering
         LIMIT ... -- your limit
    LOOP 
        BEGIN 
            SELECT ... -- your needed column(s)
              INTO ... -- your defined variable(s)
              FROM some_table -- the same table
             WHERE some_id = r.some_id -- only check this one record
               FOR UPDATE NOWAIT; -- don't wait for parallel transactions
            EXIT;
        EXCEPTION WHEN lock_not_available THEN 
            CONTINUE;
        END;
    END LOOP;
    ... -- do something based on variables, or move this before the EXIT above
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```